# Ryobi circular saw motor runs, blade doesn’t

Tags: circular-saw

Ryobi CSB142LZ - Used a fair amount.  Recently used it and made a lot of noise.   It seemed like the spindle lock was partially engaged.  Now, the spindle lock does nothing, ie, doesn’t prevent the blade from turning.  The motor runs, but the blade does not spin.  It is like the motor shaft is disconnected. Bought a new saw, but wondered if this is worth fixing.

Comment: Have you had your rainy-day teardown yet?  Totally add photos to this question - I'm curious to know how it broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not worth the effort to fix. It sounds like a broken shaft which would be far from easy to replace, and the parts are probably hard to get and/or expensive enough

Answer (score 2):

Replacementparts.com show s no gearbox for this saw so it appears you have a snapped shaft. The armature goes for about $59 and you could get a new saw for that amount so it's not worth fixing. Numerous other parts are no longer available so don't waste your money. Just for fun, take it apart and see what happened. If you're in the USA, you have time on your hands.

Comment: I started to try to disassemble just to see what happened, but it looked like quite a chore.  I’ll save it for a rainy day, which might be tomorrow.  Then it will be given a proper disposal at the landfill.

Comment: I find on my high end hand tools many times it is worth it but if the tool is under 100$ and the parts are 60 + shipping they go into the parts for other tools that break box+